# With python's prometheus_client, how to pre-calculate a bunch of metrics?

Tags: python, prometheus

Is there a way to hook into the metrics generation request to calculate the metrics first or generate a cache?

Imagine a have a structure that I need to extracts some metrics from, for example a `list` of some data that I run a loop and extract some data from that list (ie: a dictionary where the key is the metric to the value/gauge).

I could create the gauge metrics with a `g.set_function` but that would make every metric run the "extraction data" process again.

Example of what I wanted or something that would achieve that goal:

```py
# DOES NOT WORK! Not a solution.

_cache = {"A":0, "B":0}

def generate_metrics():
  _cache = do_some_calculation()

metric_a = prometheus_client.Gauge("metric_a", "Metric A").set_function(lambda: _cache["a"])

metric_b = prometheus_client.Gauge("metric_b", "Metric B").set_function(lambda: _cache["b"])

# Is there something similar to this line below?
prometheus_client.generate_cache_callback(generate_metrics)
```

Comment: Seems like you are looking for [custom collectors](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#custom-collectors).